# Primefaces Poll doesn't render content in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my backing bean i have an method providing the content of a list, which I display in JSF using the `ui:repeat` tag.

```
public List<ContentViewItem> getContentViewItemList() {
    setContentViewItemList(contentViewItemService.getContentViewItems("" + sessionBean.getSelectedProject().getId(), sessionBean.getLanguageCode()));
    return this.contentViewItemList;
}
```

The content of the list changes from another part of the application, so I want to use `p:poll` to update the list frequently.

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="commentlist">
    <ui:repeat var="contentItem" value="#{contentItemBean.contentViewItemList}">
        <li class="list-item-elements type #{contentItem.contentType == 'Partition' ? 'border-left-orange' : contentItem.contentType == 'Chunk' ? 'border-left-red' : 'border-left-red' }"
            data-ix="list-item">
            <h:outputText value="#{contentItem.description}"/>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>

<p:poll update="commentlist" listener="#{contentItemBean.refresh}"
        interval="5"/>
</h:form>
```

Because I don't need a `listener` method to do any logic, I implemented the method `refresh` returning `null` without any functionality.

The page gets rendered correctly, all items are displayed. When `p:poll` does the refresh, all items disappear. I also tried calling the getter method `getContentViewItemList` instead of refresh, but it behaves the same.

**UPDATE**

This isn't working either.

```
<h:form id="commentlist">
<h:panelGroup>
    <ui:repeat var="contentItem" value="#{contentItemBean.contentViewItemList}">
        <li class="list-item-elements type #{contentItem.contentType == 'Partition' ? 'border-left-orange' : contentItem.contentType == 'Chunk' ? 'border-left-red' : 'border-left-red' }"
            data-ix="list-item">
            <h:outputText value="#{contentItem.description}"/>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>

<h:form>
<p:poll update="commentlist" listener="#{contentItemBean.refresh}"
        interval="5"/>
</h:form>
```

**UPDATE II**
I have added a `int` variable to the backing bean, which gets incremented every call. The counter works and gets updated, when the first refresh happens, the list disappears.

Regards

Comment: Just to understand what's going on, try to separate the poll in another form and see if that would change something.

Comment: No need to update the question with a suggestion I made, won't have an added value, it was just a guess that you might have something in your form that gets in the way of your request ...

Comment: A lot of debugging you can and should do yourself. Look at the http responses (is it empty there), is `#{contentItemBean.contentViewItemList}` called in when the poll updates etc...

Comment: i'm not sure if it's related or not, but don't make `setContentViewItemList(...)` call in `getContentViewItemList()` method. that get method is called by jsf components god knows how many times.

Comment: I have to do that request that often, because nearly all 15 seconds the list changes.